# Namespace of curl in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

What is the name space of curl in symfony2? It gives Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would seem that curl support is not enabled - check your php.ini

Answer (score 2):

PHP invoke CURL with simple functions. If you have enabled the 'php_curl' extension in your php.ini, you should have no trouble invoking curl normally. But for certain configurations of PHP (I don't remember what) I was advised to use backslash before [like \curl_init();]

Answer (score 0):

There are two php.ini files for bowser and for console. Make sure that you have enabled php_curl in both. This happened to me when developing a console script. This must work for sure.